# How to handle uploading html content to an AppEngine application?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

I would like to allow my users to upload HTML content to my AppEngine web app. However if I am using the Blobstore to upload all the files (HTML files, css files, images etc.) this causes a problem as all the links to other files (pages, resources) will not work.

I see two possibilities, but both of them are not very pretty and I would like to avoid using them:

- Go over all the links in the html files and change them to the relevant blob key.
- Save a mapping between a file and a blob key, catch all the redirections and serve the blobs (could cause problems with same name files).

How can I solve this elegantly without having to go over and change my user's files?

Comment: I don't think there's any more elegant solution. Since the html needs to contain the correct paths for it's resources (css/image etc). Could you explain more what the user case is? Want should an user be able to do? On top of my head I would make a html framework around it and have the user specify the css/js in a sperate textarea and store it as text in the datastore. And make use of the blobstore for images.

Comment: @fredrik My site will be a kind of content portal and my users will be uploading interactive HTML content, games for example. I wouldn't want to enforce any rules on my users when they build their content, plus I wouldn't want to mess with their content once they upload it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving a mapping is the best option here. You'll need to identify a group of files in some way, since multiple users may upload a file with the same name, then associate unique pathnames with each file in that group. You can use key names to make it a simple datastore get to find the blob associated with a given path. No redirects are required - just use the standard Blobstore serving approach of setting the blobstore header to have App Engine serve the blob to the user.

Another option is to upload a zip, as Frederik suggests. There's no need to unpack and store the files individually, though - you can serve them directly out of the zip in blobstore, as [this demo app](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/08/Using-BlobReader-wildcard-subdomains-and-webapp2) does.

Answer (score 1):

Because app engine is running your content on multiple servers, you are not able to write to the filesystem. What you could do is ask them to upload a zip file containing their html, css, js, images,... The zipfile module from python is available in appengine, so you can unzip these files, and store them individually. This way, you know the directory structure of the zip. This allows you to create a mapping of relative paths to the content in the blobstore. I don't have enough experience with zipfile to write a full example here, I hope someone more experienced can edit my answer, or create a new one with an example.